# Typescript specific type in switch statement

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to write a function which, given an enum value, returns a specific type. Typescript isn't recognizing the properties inside switch and if statements.

```
interface A {
  a: string;
}

interface B {
  b: string;
}

enum DataType {
  a = 'a',
  b = 'b',
}

interface Type {
  [DataType.a]: A;
  [DataType.b]: B;
}

function test<T extends keyof Type>(type: T): Type[T] {
  switch (type) {
    case DataType.a:
      return {a: 'test'}; // <--- no error, but TS doesn't recognize the property
  }
}
```

Using Typescript `4.2.3`.

Comment: What specifically do you mean by "TS doesn't recognize the property", if there is no error?

Comment: @panta82 I'm afraid your issue is different because in your case `TEvent` is used in the types of two parameters, whereas in this question `T` is used in the type of one parameter and the function's return type. In this question the function is safe because if `DataType.a` is assignable to `T` then `{a: 'test'}` must be assignable to `Type[T]`. In your case your function genuinely isn't safe, because `TEvent` could be `'event1' | 'event2'`, allowing `event` to be `'event1'` while also allowing `payload` to be of type `IPayload2`. (Also, unrelated, but you're missing `break` statements.)

Comment: @kaya3, you are right. There is no way to disambiguate based on switch statement in that case. I changed the flow to use a function map instead of switch. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know it is acceptable for you, but [function overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) seems to work. If you decide to go with this solution, you will need to replace `interface Type` with a special overload signature for each case.

```js
interface A {
  a: string;
}

interface B {
  b: string;
}

enum DataType {
  a = 'a',
  b = 'b',
}

function test(value: DataType.a): A;
function test(value: DataType.b): B; 
function test(value: DataType): A | B {
  switch (value) {
    case DataType.a:
      return {a: 'testA'};
    case DataType.b:
      return {b: 'testB'};
  }
}
```

> [TypeScript playground - live example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4ChnLgLmQGcwpQBzAbiwF8stRJZEUAhTHZAI0JLJCq16EEAFcAtsgAicMHAAqATwAOKbLjjIAvMgDkcXQBpOXbXq5GhWGKJAIwwAPYhkkEgAoAbnAA2oiIQyckqqAHRwAJSEqNQ2dg7OrhAe3n4B0rIKKhChXFHIrJTI1rb2Ti5uYF6+-oGZIRD56AA+BRy4RADuwGAIABbI1WkR7bjICHBEKEFZYQScY8hQEGCiUC4YBHqVqLo01IsTUxnB2bn4C2PLq+uYPNvJYKx7B8h0NEA)

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you cannot achieve what you want with a switch statement because of the typescript limitations.
But the following solution should absolutely work for you.

```
interface A {
  a: string;
}

interface B {
  b: string;
}

enum DataType {
  a = "a",
  b = "b",
}

interface Type {
  [DataType.a]: A;
  [DataType.b]: B;
}

function test<T extends keyof Type>(type: T): Type[T] {
  return (type === DataType.a ? { a: "test" } : { b: "test" }) as Type[T];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have a group of Types that are related, and you often need to distinguish between members of that related group, then generally it is best to use a dedicated property to achieve that - TypeScript is optimized for that approach.  For example

```
type KindValues = "a" | "b"

type TT = {
  kind:KindValues,
  body: any
}

type TA = {
  kind:"a",
  body:string
}
function isTA(t:TT):t is TA { return t.kind==="a"; }

type TB = {
  kind:"b",
  body:number
}
function isTB(t:TT):t is TB { return t.kind==="b"; }

function handler(t:TT):void{
  if (isTA(t)){
    //t.body=1  // error: number is not assignable to string
    t.body = 'x';
  }
  else if (isTB(t)){
    //t.body='x'  // error: string is not assignable to number
    t.body = 1;
  }
}
```

If you want to avoid a waterfall of type checks then usually it is most flexible to create a Map from `kind` to appropriate functions.

Typescript does not require a single discriminator key.  It still works well with a second key for subtyping types, but the fewer the better it works, in terms of auto-completion.